# iPad: Login with two Apple ID like Windows users

Tags: ipad

I just bought a new iPad Mini 5 64GB Wi-Fi. I am new to iPad and Apple ecosystem.

I logged in with my Apple ID created years ago for iTunes music on my Android device.

Can I log into iPad using two separate Apple IDs like a Windows user? Like you lock one user and log into other user, so both can not access others data, apps, folders, etc.

My intention is to hide certain installed apps. Is there another way to hide game apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I log into iPad using two separate Apple IDs like a Windows user? Like you lock one user and log into other user, so both can access others data, apps, folders, etc.

No. iOS, the operating system running on iPad doesn't support multi-user login and switching mechanism (a feature commonly available in desktop operating systems).

> My intention is to hide certain installed apps. Is there another way to hide game apps?

An installed app cannot be hidden from view from the users of iOS/iPad.

Comment: Doesn't Parental Controls have an option to hide apps?

Comment: so there could be other way